# Custom tab on contenttype not working in webpart

Tags: web-part, ribbon

I've created a custom ribbon tab that shows for a specific contenttype like this:

```
  <CustomAction
   Id="IncomingDocumentTab"
   Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
   RegistrationId="0x010100476E04EA2BFC4CADA2420D300CF1433B"
   RegistrationType="ContentType">
```

The tab works fine on my library. When I add a webpart with this list to my page, the tab is not showing.

This image shows the tab in the list:
[image]

Then if i create a default lists and libraries webpart of the same list, like this way (sorry that the site is in dutch)

[image]

if I have added this webpart, the tab isn't showing.

Is it possible to show the tab when you select a document in the webpart?

In reaction of Omlin's post, I've tried to change Ribbon.Tabs._children to Ribbon.LibraryContextualGroup._children. this works for the library itself, but not for the webpart.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your two last sentences :) Do you mean that the tab is shown but not active or what? And which webpart exactly are you adding? Please, consider rephrasing or illustrating your question with a screenshot.

Comment: I've added 2 screenshots to clarify my problem :). The tab is not showing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found what I was missing. In the webpart settings, the toolbar type setting was "Summary toolbar". After I've changed it to "Full Toolbar" my tab showed up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have static tab. Unfortunately, in this case you'll need to perform some additional actions on the page where you're adding the library webpart.

More specifically, you'll need to call [MakeTabAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spribbon.maketabavailable.aspx) method, passing tab id as a parameter (and optionally, id of visibility context of the webpart). Since the document library webpart could be added on any site page, most obvious option here will be to use [Delegate Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463169.aspx) technique.

However, dealing with Delegate Controls is a dangerous habit, and I'd avoid it unless it's absolutely neccessary.

Thus, I'd recommend you to consider another approach, when your tab will appear inside "Library Tools" contextual group rather than separately.

I mean, now you have this:

[image]

and I suggest to move your "PRO/Staal" tab into "Hulpmiddelen voor bibliotheken" contextual tab group, placing it next to "Documenten" and "Bibliotheek" tabs.

This approach will allow you to avoid using Delegate Controls.

Only custom action will be required. The only thing you have to change in your current solution, is **Location** attibute value of the **CommandUIDefinition** element.

Now you have this code:

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
    <!-- tab definition goes here -->
</CommandUIDefinition>
```

And you will have to change "Ribbon.Tabs._children" to "Ribbon.LibraryContextualGroup._children":

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.LibraryContextualGroup._children">
    <!-- tab definition goes here -->
</CommandUIDefinition>
```

P.S. If you're dealing with SharePoint ribbon often, I'd recommend you to probe [Fluent Ribbon API](http://spribbon.codeplex.com) opensource project. It simplifies work with ribbon enormously, and for example at my company this library is an unofficial standard, and we use it extensively for our enterprise product.

For your particular case, Fluent Ribbon API offers [RibbonCustomAction](http://markeev.com/sharepoint/ribbon/?topic=html/ribbonCustomAction.htm) feature and convenient [AddTabToContextualGroup](http://markeev.com/sharepoint/ribbon/?topic=html/M_FluentRibbon_RibbonCustomAction_AddTabToContextualGroup.htm) method.

Comment: I've changed the location to Ribbon.LibraryContextualGroup._children, but the tab is still not showing with the webpart. Am I missing anything else?  I'm definitely going to check the FLuent Ribbon API, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Have you cleared the browser cache? Actually I've tested this approach with the only difference, that custom action was attached directly to list, rather than to a content type (but I don't think this makes any sense). And it worked perfectly.